# onDataSetChanged() on RemoteViewsFactory not being called after updating AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I have the following widget provider info:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_agenda"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="110dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="110dp"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="600000" android:widgetCategory="home_screen"/>
```

Used in the widget provider registered in the Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AgendaWidgetProvider"
    android:label="MyWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/agenda_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

My `RemoteViewsService` is registered as well:

```
<service
        android:name=".AgendaWidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

It has the following definition:

```
class AgendaWidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {

    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent?) =
        AgendaWidgetViewsFactory(applicationContext)
}
```

To force update the widget and call the `onUpdate()` method on `AgendaWidgetProvider` I send the following broadcast:

```
val widgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(
    ComponentName(context, AgendaWidgetProvider::class.java)
)
if (widgetIds.isNotEmpty()) {
    Intent(context, AgendaWidgetProvider::class.java).apply {
        this.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
        putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds)
        context.sendBroadcast(this)
    }
}
```

This gets called every time! My `onUpdate()` looks like this:

```
override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {

    appWidgetIds.forEach {

        val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_agenda)

        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetDate, "Today")

        val i = Intent(context, AgendaWidgetService::class.java)
        i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId)
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(
            R.id.widgetAgendaList,
            i
        )

        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.widgetAgendaList, R.id.widgetAgendaEmpty)

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(it, R.id.widgetDate)

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(it, R.id.widgetAgendaList)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(it, rv)
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

}
```

The `onDataSetChanged()` has the following def:

```
override fun onDataSetChanged() {
    Timber.d("AAA onDataSetChanged")
}
```

I use Android emulator (8.0) and Nexus 5x (8.1) to test this. The `onUpdate()` is called every time, while `onDataSetChanged()` seems to be called only when exiting or entering the app. Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: make sample and send link here, to reproduce

Answer (score 3):

To trigger `onDataSetChanged()` in a widget, you don't need to create a broadcast.  Just call [`notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(int[],%20int)) from within your app, like this:

```
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AgendaWidgetProvider.class));
                appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widgetAgendaList);
```

Also, you shouldn't need to call `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` in `onCreate()`.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164642/), `onCreate()` automatically triggers `onDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: You seem very expert on widgets, can I ask your opinion on a question?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure I'm an expert but I've been working with widgets lately.  Best thing is to post your question on StackOverflow to get lots of expertise.

Comment: I published it but no one answered yet.